# Shamir's Secret sharing for Key encryption

Tags: encryption, secret-sharing

I have studied Shamirs Secret Sharing(SSS) scheme. Now my doubt is to how to apply this in real time applications. I have an application which receives encrypted data from server and decrypts the data with the help of key which is stored in this application. I wanted to secure this key in the application with SSS. How can apply this technique to stored this key in application. Because once i encrypt this key with shares then those shares should be available in realtime. So please suggest how can i apply SSS in my case.

Comment: Who is going to be holding on to the shares? And if the shares are on separate devices, how will you ensure that they can communicate in real time?

Comment: @AmanGrewal , So should i assume that SSS is not useful in such scenario. Because in real time shares need to combined then only decryption will happen ?

Comment: Shamir's secret sharing is a relatively specialized tool. It works great for the specific purpose it's meant for (splitting a secret value into $n$ parts, and allowing it to be reconstructed from any $k \le n$ of those, but not from any fewer parts), but it doesn't really do much else. So, yes, unless you just happen to have one of those relatively uncommon scenarios that SSS is good for, you probably won't have any use for it.